# Wrong from address in gmail with WebMail.Send MV3 C #

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, gmail, webmail

When I send mail from my Web page is both the from and to [personalemailremoved]@gmail.com when I received the email. What do I need to change to view from mail in gmail that the user filled in on the web site?

I Use Gmail to send email in my form and receive it via gmail:

Contact.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactform" }))
    {

        <ol>
            <li>
                <label for="mail">
                    Din E-post*</label>
                @Html.TextBox("mail", null, new { @class = "text" })
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="rubrik">
                    Rubrik*</label>
                @Html.TextBox("rubrik", null, new { @class = "text" })
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="message">
                    Meddelande*</label>
                @Html.TextArea("meddelande")
            </li>
            <li class="buttons">
                <input type="submit" name="imageField" id="imageField" value="Skicka meddelande"
                    class="button" />
                <div class="clr">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ol>
    }
```

HomeController:

```
 public ActionResult Contact(string mail, string rubrik, string meddelande)
        {
            try
            {
                WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
                WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
                WebMail.UserName = "personalemailremoved@gmail.com";
                WebMail.Password = "MYPASSWORD";
                WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
                WebMail.Send(
                        "personalemailremoved@gmail.com",
                        rubrik,
                        meddelande,
                        mail
                    );

                return RedirectToAction("MailSent");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("", "Kontrollera uppgifterna");
            }

            return View("Contact");
        }
        public ActionResult MailSent()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What if you put `president@whitehouse.gov` as sender address? The receiver of the email would be scared, don't you think? That is to say that unless you are `president@whitehouse.gov` you cannot send emails on behalf of this address.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Brilliant comment. It's a trivial matter to specifiy a different From address. This is something that is done all the time. Give me your email address and I'll send you a message from yourself.

Comment: @Sixhouse, sent via the GMail smtp server?

Comment: @GvS the op doesn't list that as a requirement. Nor do I think that is what Darin was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail actually changes this to the authenticated account automatically, so you need to use another server if you want to do that.

If you don't want to use a different SMTP server, don't use any at all! When you connect to the mail server, don't give it credentials. This is how SMTP servers send mail. It is important to note that this will only work if you are only sending an email to the user with a gmail.com email address. Otherwise it thinks you are using it as an open relay. You can have other addresses in the "To:" field, you just can't add them when doing the SMTP communication. I actually did an independent study on this exact thing in college, I still have my code. You may actually need to do the SMTP communication by hand. If you need a quick guide to SMTP spec I can post a link to the handout I made that explains it (though it is less than official, it should be easier to read than the RFC).

Answer (score 1):

relaying through gmail will always set the from as the authenticated user.  for freedom to set the from address, you need to use a different smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) instead combined with ASP.NET's [Mail Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) class. Here is an example:

```
using System.Net.Mail;

// Create email code
MailMessage m = new MailMessage();

m.From = new MailAddress("address@gmail.com", "display name");
m.To.Add("address@gmail.com");
m.Subject = "subject";
m.Body = "Body";

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Your SMTP Server");
smtp.Send(m);
```

Comment: This will not work because you are still using the gmail SMTP server.

Comment: @DanBalthaser the SMTP server isn't even specified in the code example. Cleary to use it you have to enter an smtp server.

Comment: @Dan Balthaser If he is building a website, I assume he is going to have a host. Most hosts, have an SMTP server you can use.

Comment: @SixHouse You correct but I think you are missing the point. His code would also work with a different SMTP server so he does not need to change his code except for that server address.

Comment: @DanBalthaser well, yes, but you said "This will not work because you are still using the gmail SMTP server," which he is not.

Answer (score 0):

Most smtp servers, do not accept a sender other as the authenticated user. Or from the domain they are supposed to be sending mail from.

There are some free smtp server, that relay mail from every sender, but they end up on some blacklist very soon.

The owner of a domain, can [add some code to their DNS server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), to indentify mail servers that may send email in their name. This can be checked by the receiver, and the receiver can use it to identify false senders.

As you can see, it is not very easy to adjust the "From" field in an email, and still make sure the mail arrives.

You might change the "reply to" field. But also this will make your "spam score" a little higher.